# CSS Image Sprites not working in IE7

Tags: html, css

Hi, I would like to know why in IE7 my CSS Sprites images are not showing up, such as the flag icons on the top and the social media icons in the footer.

Could you please tell me why?

Here is the link  http://indivar.us/StackOverFlow/PTCNews/Website/

Answer (score 2):

Without checking your link (because the site is huge) IE7/6 require background color to be set if using a sprite. You can set it transparent also.

```
background: transparent url(../images/flags.png) no-repeat -57....
```

Comment: Here the link - http://indivar.us/StackOverFlow/PTCNews/Website/ pleaes check at the top..

Comment: Try setting also background color to transparent.. I updated my answer.

Comment: have u checked the CSS file ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it..

With reference to the link as I provided above, the CSS for FLAGS ICONS IN IE7 is mentioned below.By providing `float:left` and `display:inline` in `p.flags a`, it shows the CSS sprites images of flags!!

```
p.flags a 
{
  display:inline;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  margin-right:5px;
  position:inherit;
  float:left;
}
```